# Reading a file with structure of structures into a python

Tags: python, structure

I have a text file in the following format:

```
A {

    B {
         C {
             param1 = val1
             param2 = val2
           }
         D {
              param3 = val3
              param4 = val4
           }
       }
}
```

My objective is to read a single structure from structs-of-structs, such as 'C' alone from above file format. Crude way to do is process line-by-line and save the parameters from the intended structure in a list or dictionary. This method impacts a lot on performance.

Is there a better way or in-built python module ready for usage ?

Comment: Is this really the content of file? I think you are missing `:` after *key*. For example: `A: {`. And also `,` after each value

Comment: You'll need to build a custom parser for such a non-standard structure. The best way to do this probably involves the [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) module.

Comment: @anonymous, if you are thinking that it as a json object, no it is not. This is file format generated from a 'C' code. But is there a simple way in which i can convert this to a json object and read using json modules ??

Comment: @Sravan: If you are having the access to C code, i will suggest to change the code to make it write in JSON format (or any other universally recognised fornat). JSON is the standard format, and you may access the content anywhere, independent of language/platform (all the modern laguages have `JSON` library). If you write your custom parser, there will be a lot of scenarios you need to handle and you will end tweeking up the code for weeks

Comment: Python loves JSON. `import json; thing = json.loads(json_string)`. Python maps JSON { ... } to a dict and [ ... ] to a list.

Comment: @anonymous, sadly don't have control or access to C-code.

Comment: Read: [Tips on how to parse custom file format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2036276/2063361)

Comment: You might consider ANTLR which could easily chew through this and give you language extension capabilities.